# Как узнать имя переменной в которой храниться кнопка при нажатии которой вызвался этот метод?

Tags: python, pyqt5

При нажатии кнопки создаётся новый (точно такой же как и прошлый) groupbox

```py
def new(self):

    self.groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    self.groupBox_2.setMinimumSize(QSize(411, 251))
    self.groupBox_2.setMaximumSize(QSize(411, 251))
    self.groupBox_2.setCheckable(False)
    self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(u"border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;\n"
"border-radius: 10;")
```

В этом groupbox'е находится кнопка deleten

```py
self.deleten_2 = QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
self.deleten_2.setGeometry(QRect(378, 10, 24, 24))
font = QFont()
font.setPointSize(10)
self.deleten_2.setFont(font)
self.deleten_2.setText("X")
self.deleten_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
self.deleten_2.setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton {"
    "    background-color: None;"
    "    border: 2px solid white;"
    "    border-radius: 7;"
    "    color: white;"
    "}"
    ""
    "QPushButton:hover {"
    "    background-color: #FF381E;"
    "    border-color: #FF381E;"
    "    color: white;"
    "}"
    ""
    "")

self.deleten_2.clicked.connect(self.delete)
```

Привязал к кнопке (ну, а так как они создаются каждый раз при нажатии кнопки, то к
*кнопкам) действие при нажатии на неё

```py
self.deleten_2.clicked.connect(self.delete)
```

*Каждый раз при нажатии кнопки создаётся один и тот же groupbox, соответственно и кнопка deleten (это имя переменной в которой она находится) остаётся неизменной. То есть мне нужно, чтобы когда будет нажата одна из этих кнопок deleten мне нужно узнать название прееменной в которой находится кнопка, которая активировала это действие. Каким способом это можно сделать?*

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Название переменной узнать будет тяжело, может, даже невозможно.

Намного проще задавать каждой кнопке атрибут `.objectName`, а уже потом обрабатывать его, вместо названия переменной.

```
...
self.deleten_2.setObjectName('deleted_2')
...
```

А потом - получать `.objectName`:

```
...
self.sender().objectName
...
```